# Should we still support iOS 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, graceful-degradation

Now that [iOS 5 is out and compatible with iPhone 3GS & up](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#promofooter), should we still support iOS 4?

Comment: This is a silly question.  It obviously depends on your particular situation.

Comment: I still use iOS 3.2, and I refuse to install any app that requires upgrading because I can't be bothered with the nightmare of an upgrade, I guess you have to ask if the customers like me are worth the extra effort (if there is any extra effort)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is if you want to live as close to the edge with Apple that you support the current and previous releases. That means with iOS 5 in the wild that you continue to support iOS 4 until iOS 6 is released.

Answer (score 3):

If iOS 5 specific features aren't needed, then YES. People with iPhone 3G's and older iPod Touches won't be able to upgrade to iOS5. Also, there is a lag in how long it takes for the entire population of app users to migrate to iOS5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to [Read Write Web](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/25_million_people_are_using_ios_5_despite_early_hi.php), 25 million people have updated to iOS5, which is only about 25% according to an [article from March 2011](http://www.startupsmart.com.au/technology/2011-03-03/apple-unveils-ipad-2-on-sale-in-australia-on-march-25.html).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely NOT, there is still a ton of users running iOS 4.0, besides there isn't that much that you can do with iOS 5.0 that you can't with iOS 4.0